# NullPointerExceptions on arraylist

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, null, nullpointerexception

I am trying to make a snake-type game in Java.

To do so, I am using lists to keep hold every of the snake's body parts with

`ArrayList<SnakeBodyPart> snakeBodyParts = new ArrayList<SnakeBodyPart>();`.

I declare and initiate a variable, `SnakeBodyPart SnakeBodyPart = null;`.

I then add a body part to the snake with `snakeBodyParts.add(SnakeBodyPart);`.

(Not the most efficient way, I guess, but it'll have to do.)

But for some reason, whenever I run the script, I get

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`,

and that the error is

`at game.Snake.<init>(Snake.java:60)`

in the Java console.

I want to know what the problem is. Here is the code for the SnakeBodyPart.

```
class SnakeBodyPart{
    int x,y,direction;
    void move(){
        if(direction == 0){
            y -= 50;
        }
        if(direction == 1){
            x += 50;
        }
        if(direction == 2){
            y += 50;
        }
        if(direction == 3){
            x -= 50;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Line 60 is `snakeBodyParts.get(0).direction = 0;`.

Comment: Come on! Read the exception! The problem is at Snake.java line 60. That's what we need to see!

Comment: `SnakeBodyPart SnakeBodyPart = null;.` is your problem. You need to have an instance assigned to the variable before calling a method on it: `snakeBodyParts.add(SnakeBodyPart);` Do something like `SnakeBodyPart sbp = new SnakeBodyPart();` assuming there's a no-arg constructor in the class.

Comment: kon, put that in an answer, not a comment

Comment: have you created the snakeBodyParts?

Comment: @Kon - You can add `null` to an ArrayList. That won't throw a NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done this:

```
  SnakeBodyPart snakeBodyPart = null;
```

Create the object

```
  SnakeBodyPart snakeBodyPart = new SnakeBodyPart();
```

Since `snakeBodyPart` is `null`, you are getting `NullPointerException` in `Line 60`. You are calling `get()` method on `null` as `snakeBodyParts.get(0).direction = 0;`